# The hidden item is not showing correctly where I want it

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

When the user clicks on 32, I would like to display just after the line a new hidden table.

My problem is that the hidden table is at the bottom of the first table.

[image]

Sorry I don't know if this is an Angular problem? Maybe HTML or CSS?

Here is my code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lehqcj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

*file.HTML*

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%; text-align: center;">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">LABEL</th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">LABEL</th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">LABEL</th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">LABEL</th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 10%; ">LABEL</th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 14%; background-color: #dee2e657; ">
            LABEL
         </th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;">LABEL</th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">LABEL</th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 9%;">LABEL</th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">LABEL</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">10</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">30</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">58</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">11</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10%; ">17</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 12%; background-color: #dee2e657;">
         <button (click)="toggle()" id="bt">{{ 32 }}</button>
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10%; ">44</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">20</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">10</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">11</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">20</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">40</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">18</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">31</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10%; ">27</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 12%; background-color: #dee2e657;">47</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10%; ">25</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">21</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">90</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">51</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<ng-container *ngIf="show">
   <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%; text-align: center;">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">NAME</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">FIRST NAME</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
   </table>
</ng-container>
```

*file.TS*

```
export class AppComponent {
  public show: boolean = false;
  public buttonName: any = 'Show';

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;

    // CHANGE THE NAME OF THE BUTTON.
    if (this.show) this.buttonName = 'Hide';
    else this.buttonName = 'Show';
  }
}
```

Comment: you can fix this with the help of CSS or you can move the HTML part with the TD tag

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qqm243

Comment: Why don't you use Angular Material Table with expandable rows. Inside the content you can make your custom table.

With your current approach You are showing the hidden Table after your first table so that is where it will get rendered. You have to show it right below the button which and this is not related to angular at all.

Comment: @Naren Murali: Thank you Naren Murali, it is exactly what I want !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution, but not the best.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qqm243?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thank you but It is possible to center Name and FirstName ??

Comment: @pops1348 updated my stackblitz

Comment: I have adapted my table on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdrf9n?file=src/app/app.component.html). I still have the same problem :-(

Comment: @pops1348 Yes I saw your new question, will try to come up with something